# Apply a mathematical operation to all columns of dataframe by group [R]

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble, mutate

I have the given dataframe :

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("2023-02-15_10-30-49", "2023-02-15_10-30-49", 
"2023-02-15_10-30-49", "2023-02-15_10-30-49", "2023-02-15_10-30-49", 
"2023-02-15_10-30-49", "2023-02-15_10-30-49", "2023-02-15_10-30-49", 
"2023-02-15_10-30-49", "2023-02-15_10-30-49", "2023-02-15_10-30-49", 
"2023-02-15_10-30-49", "2023-02-15_10-30-49", "2023-02-15_10-30-49", 
"2023-02-15_10-33-16", "2023-02-15_10-33-16", "2023-02-15_10-33-16", 
"2023-02-15_10-33-16", "2023-02-15_10-33-16", "2023-02-15_10-33-16", 
"2023-02-15_10-33-16", "2023-02-15_10-33-16", "2023-02-15_10-33-16", 
"2023-02-15_10-33-16", "2023-02-15_10-33-16", "2023-02-15_10-33-16", 
"2023-02-15_10-33-16", "2023-02-15_10-33-16", "2023-02-15_10-33-16", 
"2023-02-15_10-33-16", "2023-02-15_10-33-16", "2023-02-15_10-33-16", 
"2023-02-15_10-33-46", "2023-02-15_10-33-46", "2023-02-15_10-33-46", 
"2023-02-15_10-33-46", "2023-02-15_10-33-46", "2023-02-15_10-33-46", 
"2023-02-15_10-33-46", "2023-02-15_10-33-46", "2023-02-15_10-33-46", 
"2023-02-15_10-33-46", "2023-02-15_10-33-46", "2023-02-15_10-33-46"
), V3 = c(93051, 93052, 93053, 93054, 93055, 93056, 93057, 93058, 
93059, 93100, 93101, 93102, 93103, 93104, 93318, 93319, 93320, 
93321, 93322, 93323, 93324, 93325, 93326, 93327, 93328, 93329, 
93330, 93331, 93332, 93333, 93334, 93335, 93348, 93349, 93350, 
93351, 93352, 93353, 93354, 93355, 93356, 93357, 93358, 93359
), V4 = c(5019.00214, 5019.00215, 5019.00216, 5019.00217, 5019.00218, 
5019.00214, 5019.00215, 5019.00215, 5019.00215, 5019.00215, 5019.00215, 
5019.00215, 5019.00214, 5019.00214, 5019.00198, 5019.00194, 5019.00193, 
5019.00193, 5019.00216, 5019.00194, 5019.00194, 5019.00194, 5019.00194, 
5019.00194, 5019.00194, 5019.00194, 5019.00194, 5019.00194, 5019.00194, 
5019.00195, 5019.00195, 5019.00195, 5019.00175, 5019.00175, 5019.00175, 
5019.00175, 5019.00175, 5019.00174, 5019.00175, 5019.00175, 5019.00175, 
5019.00174, 5019.00173, 5019.00173), V6 = c(500.86491, 500.86495, 
500.86497, 500.86498, 500.86499, 500.86375, 500.86374, 500.86372, 
500.86372, 500.86372, 500.86373, 500.86372, 500.86373, 500.86372, 
500.86428, 500.86419, 500.86421, 500.86423, 500.86392, 500.86343, 
500.86341, 500.86341, 500.86342, 500.86342, 500.86342, 500.86342, 
500.86342, 500.86342, 500.86342, 500.86344, 500.86343, 500.86343, 
500.86318, 500.86319, 500.86318, 500.86318, 500.86318, 500.86318, 
500.86315, 500.86315, 500.86315, 500.86315, 500.86313, 500.86312
), V8 = c(235.314, 235.423, 235.502, 235.556, 235.606, 230.496, 
230.502, 230.561, 230.556, 230.553, 230.564, 230.555, 230.59, 
230.598, 233.154, 233.162, 233.155, 233.142, 230.303, 230.491, 
230.464, 230.457, 230.466, 230.474, 230.472, 230.482, 230.479, 
230.476, 230.488, 230.496, 230.497, 230.499, 230.518, 230.525, 
230.514, 230.515, 230.531, 230.539, 230.507, 230.506, 230.509, 
230.513, 230.502, 230.486), V10 = c(0.38, 0.37, 0.37, 0.37, 0.36, 
0.037, 0.025, 0.014, 0.014, 0.014, 0.014, 0.014, 0.014, 0.014, 
0.37, 0.37, 0.37, 0.37, 1.2, 0.014, 0.014, 0.014, 0.014, 0.014, 
0.014, 0.014, 0.015, 0.015, 0.014, 0.014, 0.014, 0.014, 0.016, 
0.018, 0.018, 0.019, 0.021, 0.098, 0.015, 0.014, 0.014, 0.014, 
0.014, 0.014), V11 = c(0.75, 0.73, 0.71, 0.7, 0.69, 0.056, 0.04, 
0.017, 0.015, 0.015, 0.015, 0.015, 0.014, 0.015, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 
0.6, 0.82, 0.017, 0.017, 0.019, 0.021, 0.021, 0.022, 0.022, 0.024, 
0.023, 0.021, 0.019, 0.018, 0.019, 0.023, 0.026, 0.028, 0.029, 
0.035, 0.15, 0.024, 0.022, 0.021, 0.019, 0.02, 0.022)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-44L))
```

And I would like, for each selected column, extract the difference between the value of a given observation and the mean value, and that for each group("id"). I tried this, but it does not work...

```
df %>% group_split(id) %>% map(~ mutate(., across(c("V4":"V11"), ~. - mean(.))))
```

**EDIT**

Once I restarted my session, my code worked properly. Consequently, there is no real problem here. Nevertheless, I find the answers interesting. So I am going to keep this question open, for other users.

Answer (score 3):

1. No need to `group_split` it, we can use `group_by` (or `.by=`) to simplify a little (e.g., no need for `map`);
2. `funs` is deprecated, we'll assign to the `.fns=` argument directly with a `~`-function.

```r
df %>%
  mutate(across("V4":"V11", ~ . - mean(.)), .by = id)
#                     id    V3            V4            V6         V8          V10           V11
# 1  2023-02-15_10-30-49 93051 -1.142857e-05  7.421429e-04  3.0014286  0.236428571  4.798571e-01
# 2  2023-02-15_10-30-49 93052 -1.428572e-06  7.821429e-04  3.1104286  0.226428571  4.598571e-01
# 3  2023-02-15_10-30-49 93053  8.571428e-06  8.021429e-04  3.1894286  0.226428571  4.398571e-01
# 4  2023-02-15_10-30-49 93054  1.857143e-05  8.121429e-04  3.2434286  0.226428571  4.298571e-01
# 5  2023-02-15_10-30-49 93055  2.857143e-05  8.221429e-04  3.2934286  0.216428571  4.198571e-01
# 6  2023-02-15_10-30-49 93056 -1.142857e-05 -4.178571e-04 -1.8165714 -0.106571429 -2.141429e-01
# 7  2023-02-15_10-30-49 93057 -1.428572e-06 -4.278571e-04 -1.8105714 -0.118571429 -2.301429e-01
# 8  2023-02-15_10-30-49 93058 -1.428572e-06 -4.478571e-04 -1.7515714 -0.129571429 -2.531429e-01
# 9  2023-02-15_10-30-49 93059 -1.428572e-06 -4.478571e-04 -1.7565714 -0.129571429 -2.551429e-01
# 10 2023-02-15_10-30-49 93100 -1.428572e-06 -4.478571e-04 -1.7595714 -0.129571429 -2.551429e-01
# 11 2023-02-15_10-30-49 93101 -1.428572e-06 -4.378571e-04 -1.7485714 -0.129571429 -2.551429e-01
# 12 2023-02-15_10-30-49 93102 -1.428572e-06 -4.478571e-04 -1.7575714 -0.129571429 -2.551429e-01
# 13 2023-02-15_10-30-49 93103 -1.142857e-05 -4.378571e-04 -1.7225714 -0.129571429 -2.561429e-01
# 14 2023-02-15_10-30-49 93104 -1.142857e-05 -4.478571e-04 -1.7145714 -0.129571429 -2.551429e-01
# ...
```

FYI, we can use `scale` for this as well:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(across("V4":"V11", ~ scale(., scale = FALSE)), .by = id)
```

Comment: It's very nice of you to try to improve OP's code! May I ask is there any reason that you keep the double quotes around the column names (e.g. `"V4":"V11"` instead of `V4:V11`)?

Comment: Thank you for this really complete answer. Nonetheless, it only works when I restarted my session. I do not know why. And once the session restarted, the code that I wanted to use worked as well. 
I do not know if I have to delete the question because, in fine, my code worked. So there is no real problem.

Comment: @benson23, I didn't change it because it was not affecting the results. I tend to _not_ use quotes myself, but I didn't want to impost changes based solely on "style" or subjective preference without being based on efficiency, speed, or some other objective rationale. In this case, splitting the frame (when not otherwise necessary) imposes memory inefficiencies, which can be faster depending on the data size.

Comment: `s/impost/impose/`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_split(id) %>% map(~ mutate(., across(V4:V11, \(x) x - mean(x))))

[[1]]
# A tibble: 14 × 7
   id                     V3          V4        V6    V8    V10    V11
   <chr>               <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 2023-02-15_10-30-49 93051 -0.0000114   0.000742  3.00  0.236  0.480
 2 2023-02-15_10-30-49 93052 -0.00000143  0.000782  3.11  0.226  0.460
 3 2023-02-15_10-30-49 93053  0.00000857  0.000802  3.19  0.226  0.440
 4 2023-02-15_10-30-49 93054  0.0000186   0.000812  3.24  0.226  0.430
 5 2023-02-15_10-30-49 93055  0.0000286   0.000822  3.29  0.216  0.420
 6 2023-02-15_10-30-49 93056 -0.0000114  -0.000418 -1.82 -0.107 -0.214
 7 2023-02-15_10-30-49 93057 -0.00000143 -0.000428 -1.81 -0.119 -0.230
 8 2023-02-15_10-30-49 93058 -0.00000143 -0.000448 -1.75 -0.130 -0.253
 9 2023-02-15_10-30-49 93059 -0.00000143 -0.000448 -1.76 -0.130 -0.255
10 2023-02-15_10-30-49 93100 -0.00000143 -0.000448 -1.76 -0.130 -0.255
11 2023-02-15_10-30-49 93101 -0.00000143 -0.000438 -1.75 -0.130 -0.255
12 2023-02-15_10-30-49 93102 -0.00000143 -0.000448 -1.76 -0.130 -0.255
13 2023-02-15_10-30-49 93103 -0.0000114  -0.000438 -1.72 -0.130 -0.256
14 2023-02-15_10-30-49 93104 -0.0000114  -0.000448 -1.71 -0.130 -0.255

[[2]]
# A tibble: 18 × 7
   id                     V3          V4        V6     V8    V10    V11
   <chr>               <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 2023-02-15_10-33-16 93318  0.0000250   0.000651  2.09   0.211  0.406
 2 2023-02-15_10-33-16 93319 -0.0000150   0.000561  2.10   0.211  0.406
 3 2023-02-15_10-33-16 93320 -0.0000250   0.000581  2.09   0.211  0.406
 4 2023-02-15_10-33-16 93321 -0.0000250   0.000601  2.08   0.211  0.406
 5 2023-02-15_10-33-16 93322  0.000205    0.000291 -0.761  1.04   0.626
 6 2023-02-15_10-33-16 93323 -0.0000150  -0.000199 -0.573 -0.145 -0.176
 7 2023-02-15_10-33-16 93324 -0.0000150  -0.000219 -0.600 -0.145 -0.176
 8 2023-02-15_10-33-16 93325 -0.0000150  -0.000219 -0.607 -0.145 -0.175
 9 2023-02-15_10-33-16 93326 -0.0000150  -0.000209 -0.598 -0.145 -0.173
10 2023-02-15_10-33-16 93327 -0.0000150  -0.000209 -0.590 -0.145 -0.173
11 2023-02-15_10-33-16 93328 -0.0000150  -0.000209 -0.592 -0.145 -0.172
12 2023-02-15_10-33-16 93329 -0.0000150  -0.000209 -0.582 -0.145 -0.172
13 2023-02-15_10-33-16 93330 -0.0000150  -0.000209 -0.585 -0.144 -0.170
14 2023-02-15_10-33-16 93331 -0.0000150  -0.000209 -0.588 -0.144 -0.170
15 2023-02-15_10-33-16 93332 -0.0000150  -0.000209 -0.576 -0.145 -0.173
16 2023-02-15_10-33-16 93333 -0.00000500 -0.000189 -0.568 -0.145 -0.175
17 2023-02-15_10-33-16 93334 -0.00000500 -0.000199 -0.567 -0.145 -0.176
18 2023-02-15_10-33-16 93335 -0.00000500 -0.000199 -0.565 -0.145 -0.175

[[3]]
# A tibble: 12 × 7
   id                    V3       V4       V6       V8      V10      V11
   <chr>              <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 2023-02-15_10-33-… 93348  5.00e-6  1.83e-5  4.25e-3 -0.00692 -1.19e-2
 2 2023-02-15_10-33-… 93349  5.00e-6  2.83e-5  1.13e-2 -0.00492 -8.92e-3
 3 2023-02-15_10-33-… 93350  5.00e-6  1.83e-5  2.50e-4 -0.00492 -6.92e-3
 4 2023-02-15_10-33-… 93351  5.00e-6  1.83e-5  1.25e-3 -0.00392 -5.92e-3
 5 2023-02-15_10-33-… 93352  5.00e-6  1.83e-5  1.73e-2 -0.00192  8.33e-5
 6 2023-02-15_10-33-… 93353 -5.00e-6  1.83e-5  2.52e-2  0.0751   1.15e-1
 7 2023-02-15_10-33-… 93354  5.00e-6 -1.17e-5 -6.75e-3 -0.00792 -1.09e-2
 8 2023-02-15_10-33-… 93355  5.00e-6 -1.17e-5 -7.75e-3 -0.00892 -1.29e-2
 9 2023-02-15_10-33-… 93356  5.00e-6 -1.17e-5 -4.75e-3 -0.00892 -1.39e-2
10 2023-02-15_10-33-… 93357 -5.00e-6 -1.17e-5 -7.50e-4 -0.00892 -1.59e-2
11 2023-02-15_10-33-… 93358 -1.50e-5 -3.17e-5 -1.17e-2 -0.00892 -1.49e-2
12 2023-02-15_10-33-… 93359 -1.50e-5 -4.17e-5 -2.77e-2 -0.00892 -1.29e-2
```

Comment: Thank you for this good answer. Nonetheless, it only works when I restarted my session. I do not know why. And once the session restarted, the code that I wanted to use worked as well. 
I do not know if I have to delete the question because, in fine, my code worked. So there is no real problem.

Comment: @C.Guff I think you can delete the question if you don't think it's useful to the site (or to you) :)

Comment: I made an edit, to specify there is no real problem on my code. But due to interesting answers, it will be nice to keep it for other users.